# How to create a glass card with custom view\layout?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, google-gdk

Is there any way to create a glass Live card with a custom layout?

Any equivalent to Activity's `setContentView(layoutId)`?

Do I create a special xml file or is it the same as with regular Android Views or Popup Views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're two ways to rendering content on a live card, as documented at https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/timeline/LiveCard

Elad's way is the first, and what you want - "Inflating a layout using remote views". The live card so created is called low-frequency live card.

The other way is drawing directly on a live card surface, using for example Canvas API. The live card so created is called high-frequency live card.

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui/live-cards has some further doc explaining and sample code showing how to create the two types of live cards.

Answer (score 0):

```
   LiveCard liveCard; // initialized elsewhere
     RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
             R.layout.my_layout);
     liveCard.setViews(views);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CardBuilder for building Glass style cards

```
mLiveCard = new LiveCard(this, LIVE_CARD_TAG);

RemoteViews remoteView = new CardBuilder(getApplicationContext(), CardBuilder.Layout.TEXT)
                .setText("You can also add images to the background of a TEXT card.")
                .setFootnote("This is the footnote")
                .setTimestamp("just now")
                .addImage(R.drawable.ic_lap)
                .getRemoteViews();
        mLiveCard.setViews(remoteView);
```

More examples check this gdk link [card_design](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/card-design)